# how to group same values into Excel array

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

I have a duplicate value in `column A` with different value in `column B` and `column C`.

For example:

There are 3 column which is `A`, `B` and `C`. 
 - `A` has duplicate value which is serial number
 - `B` is whether it fail the test or not
 - `C` is the time for testing.

Is it possible with Excel to find time difference between time for first fail and pass?

I want to delete the data that have **less than 12 hour** so that I know the things don't need rework, just retest. I want to know the exact number of modules that need rework.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and why is it not working (expected vs. actual outcome)?

Comment: I don't have any idea on how to do it. I have around 4k data that need too be analyze. My friend show me on how to do using macro but it doesn't seem possible because the sample size of the same serial number is not the same. For now I just look at it manually and delete it manually. It kind of tedious and I want to search and try if there other way.

Comment: I can show you a formula for the time difference between the last fail and the pass. I have an idea how to get the first one, but it'd take a fair amount of work.

Comment: That's just more background information which hardly can be used to answer your question and which doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: @Matts I want the time between the first fail and first pass. This is because I want to know which module is true reject. The operator might run test couple of time so there will be multiple fail record and one pass record within couple of minutes with each other . I assume if the first fail and first pass record is more than 12 hour they reroute the module for rework. If you got any idea I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(B7 = "pass",B6 = "fail", A7 = A6),TEXT(C7-C6, "h:mm"), "")
```

To get the difference between last fail and pass use this formula in cell D7. If the cell in column B is pass and previous cell was a fail, it will work out the time difference between the previous cell that was a fail. It will also check that the cell in column A matches previous cell in column A. Can also try using Index / Match or Vlookup to get the first fail by formula. As Tim Williams said a pivot table will also help. I don't use them much, so I'm not sure how to get the time difference with a pivot table, but it'll make viewing the data easier.

You could also try adapting this formula, by nesting conditions to get the previous cell that is the first fail. Work out the maximum number of cells between a pass and a first fail, and nest it that many times. If there are cases where the fail time is later than the pass it will throw an error. If you have multiple consecutive pass cells, for the same element you'd need to add more conditions to account for that, but if there's only 1 pass per element this should work.

```
=IF(AND(B7="pass",B5="fail",A7=A5),TEXT(C7-C5,"h:mm"),IF(AND(B7="pass",B6="fail",A7=A6),TEXT(C7-C6,"h:mm"),""))
```